# How can I find out what car this set of tail lights came off of

Tags: tail-lights, vehicle-identification

I am trying to figure out what kinda car these are off ???  Click for full size picture.

[image: Front of headlight]

[image: Rear of headlight]

Answer (score 10):

Use Google lens on your phone; quite useful, allowing search by camera. I pointed it to the top image, and immediately got back a whole bunch of matching lights which appear to show the light is a 2001-2003 Honda Civic coupe tail light set.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to @Chris's great answer, if you type in the first code on the back of the light ("KS-HD323") and Google it ("[KS-HD323 light](https://www.google.com/search?q=KS-HD323%20light)") there are several hits that indicate it is a tail light for a 2001-2003 Civic Coupe:

[image: Google results for "KS-HD323 light"]